Connecting to Multiple Instances of SSIS on the Same Server
I have a server that I inherited that has multiple versions of SSIS installed (11,12,14, 15) on it. See Screen shot

Based on my understanding, in order to connect to a specific version of SSIS you must have the associated SQL Server Management Studio to manage the specific version. I am trying to connect to my SSIS version 15 instance using SSMS version 2019. However, in doing so I get the dreaded "Class Not Registered" Error, which tells me that the SSMS 2019 is trying to connect to one of the other instances. Is there a way to tell SSMS to connect to a specific instance of SSIS?

Currently, I can connect SSMS 2012 to SSIS 11 and SSMS 2014 to SSIS 12 and SSMS 2017 to SSIS 14 but for some reason SSMS 2019.1 will not connect to SSIS 15.4382.1. I have tried to go through a variety of different articles but to no avail. If anyone has any suggestions, it would be appreciated.

Fortunately, in the distant future, the version of SSMS will not be linked to a version of SQL Server/SSIS.

After some more research and testing, I was able to install SSMS 18.12.1 and it was alloed to connect to the SSIS 15.4382.1 / 2019. This is kind of odd since SSMS 19.1 should be allowed to connect to SSIS 2019 but was not. I used and suggest the following reference and setup matching build (major) numbers to determine which version to install. SQL Server Versions Web site
IMO, this is something MS should be embarrassed with. This appears to be a long standing ongoing issue with SSIS and SSMS in which something MS should address. At least put a message on screen stating you are attempting to connect to an incompatible version of the service (SSIS) vs the client (SSMS) you are connecting with, No, we get "Class Not Registred" for over 15 years.
